# Need to modify each SoapUI request json before running the test runner

Tags: soapui

I've not written a lot of Groovy code and I'm also new to SoapUI. I've done most of my testing with Perl, Python or in extreme cases bash under Linux. I only have SoapUI with Groovy on my Windows machine.

I have some 80 REST testSteps that will be run with a Groovy script that needs to run external commands to get results. The data in the testStep is JSON and rather large. I need to change one attribute:

`{ ... "currentTR": 1692201561000, ... }`

I've done various searches and they tend to lead to getting the results and modifying that. What I've not been able to find is how to get the request before the testStep is run by the Groovy script, modify it accordingly and run the testStep with the modified data.

The code I've written so far has been just able to get the testScript objects and print each name.

SoapUI 5.7,1
Windows 10

I've written some Groovy code to iterate of the testCase to get the testStep and print out each step's name and then execute an external powershell command.

Comment: Do you mean you need to do something like search and replace **one time**, or are you asking to do this dynamically **each time** the test is run?

Comment: Each time the test is run. A coworker found this solution:
`{ ... "currentTR": :"${=java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()}",  ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution a coworker found:

```
{ ... "currentTR":"${=java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()}",  ... }
```

This works very well.